# ¿Por qué sale este error al usar Python en Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext

Al momento de configurar el sublime text, me sale un mensaje error cuando quiero usar python.

```
FileNotFoundError(2, 'El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado', None, 2)
```

Así se ve el mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido! Nos podés dar más información sobre tu código. Este link tiene buenos tips para ayudarnos a entender mejor tu problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Podés tratar de abrir la carpeta donde está el archivo en cuestión: https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/7923/sublime-text-2---mostrar-el-archivo-en-la-barra-lateral-de-navegacion - Tal vez nos dé más ideas.

Comment: Esto es un error de sublime.. probaste reinstalarlo?

Comment: desinstale el programa y volví a instalarlo pero sigue el error algún otro programa con similar función soy nuevo en este hermosos mundo de la programación.

Comment: ¿Será que la instalación debe hacerse con permisos de admin o Defender puede bloquear algo?

Comment: Desinstala el susodicho python e instálalo de nuevo seleccionando "ADD TO PATH..."

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente se borró un archivo de tu editor o la instalacion no se completo de manera adecuada, te recomiendo re instalar y si persiste el error, podrias ingresar al sistema operativo en modo de pruebas e intentar para verificar que no tienes un software de terceros que te impide llevar a cabo la instalacion.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que no está encontrando es el ejecutable de `Python`.

1. Dependiendo la versión de `python` que tengas, ve hasta donde se encuentre tu ejecutable de `Python` y copia la ruta, por ejemplo en mi caso tengo la versión 3.6.0 y la ruta sería `C:\Users\TU_USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`
2. Ahora copia esa ruta y vas a Variables de entorno del PC. Una vez allí le pegas esa ruta al valor Path dentro de "Variables del Sistema".

Eso debería solucionar tu problema.
Me cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Faltaría saber qué es lo que estabas tratando de configurar, pero al parecer el problema es que sublime no encuentra el sistema de compilación de python.

Primero tienes que revisar que si tengas python instalado, y de ser así entonces tienes que agregar las variables de entorno de la PC. Das botón derecho en mi PC `-->` Propiedades `-->` Configuración avanzada del sistema `-->` Variables de entorno `-->` Variables del sistema - PATH `-->` Editar `-->` Nuevo
y agregas la ruta donde encontraste el .exe de python.

En mi caso instalé Anaconda, así que ahí es donde se encuentra el archivo.